# Mass SMS Program

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am working on a program where I will text a message to my Twilio number and have it send the message out to a group of people. I want the numbers to read from either a SQL database (so that people can sign up on a website via PHP) or through a Google Sheets spreadsheet. I really don't know where to start and was wondering if I could get some input from the pros.

Thank you!

Anthony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If what you're looking for is using Google Spreadsheets, we actually have a pretty comprehensive tutorial on how to use Google Spreadsheets with PHP [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/03/google-spreadsheets-and-php.html).

But the gist is the following:

1. Enable your spreadsheet for programmatic access
2. Start reading the data from it and loop through your records.

Looping through your records can be as easy as this:

```
// Get our spreadsheet
$spreadsheet = (new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService)
   ->getSpreadsheetFeed()
   ->getByTitle('Phone Numbers');

// Get the first worksheet (tab)
$worksheets = $spreadsheet->getWorksheetFeed()->getEntries();
$worksheet = $worksheets[0];

$listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed();

/** @var ListEntry */
foreach ($listFeed->getEntries() as $entry) {
   $phone = $entry->getValues();
}
```

On the loop above, you could also use the Twilio REST api to start sending SMS messages with Twilio as follows:

$sms = $client->account->messages->create(

```
// the number we are sending to - Any phone number
$phone,

array(
    // Step 6: Change the 'From' number below to be a valid Twilio number 
    // that you've purchased
    'from' => "YOUR_NUMBER", 

    // the sms body
    'body' => "Hey $name, Monkey Party at 6PM. Bring Bananas!"
)
);
```

So it's just a matter of using the two together. you can read more about sending messages with PHP [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/sending-via-rest).

Hope this helps you out

Comment: So you would use the sheet to update the contact numbers and all, correct? And then in order to run both, will each one be in PHP? Sorry for all of the questions, I am very new to PHP coding.

Comment: You could have them both in the same program yeah.